# Source of @type tag in docblock

Tags: php, docblocks

I found an old library that uses the `@type` tag inside dockblocks, more specifically to define classs properties, [e.g.](https://github.com/milesj/uploader/blob/master/Model/Behavior/AttachmentBehavior.php):

```php
/**
 * Mapping of database columns to attachment fields.
 *
 * @type array
 */
protected $_columns = array();
```

```php
/**
 * Default transform settings.
 *
 * @type array {
 *      @type string $class         The transform method / class to use
 *      @type string $nameCallback  Method to format filename with
 *      @type string $append        What to append to the end of the filename
 *      @type string $prepend       What to prepend to the beginning of the filename
 *      @type string $uploadDir     Directory to move file to after upload to make it publicly accessible
 *      @type string $transportDir  Directory to place files in after transporting
 *      @type string $finalPath     The final path to prepend to file names (like a domain)
 *      @type string $dbColumn      Database column to write file path to
 *      @type string $defaultPath   Default image if no file is uploaded
 *      @type bool $overwrite       Overwrite a file with the same name if it exists
 *      @type bool $self            Should the transforms apply to the uploaded file instead of creating new images
 * }
 */
protected $_transformSettings = array(
    'class' => '',
    'nameCallback' => '',
    'append' => '',
    'prepend' => '',
    'uploadDir' => '',
    'transportDir' => '',
    'finalPath' => '',
    'dbColumn' => '',
    'defaultPath' => '',
    'overwrite' => false,
    'self' => false
);
```

I haven't been able to find any reference to such tag in any of the common tools ([phpDocumentor/1](https://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.pkg.html), [phpDocumentor/2](https://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/index.html), [DocBlox](https://github.com/dzuelke/Docblox/blob/master/docs/manual/04%20-%20Anatomy%20of%20a%20DocBlock.md)...).

Do you know which tool/document does this tag possibly come from?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing, which I found is [this](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/inline-documentation-standards/php/). Where it is described in a table of PHPDoc Tags, which are commonly used in WordPress as:

> Used to denote argument array value types. See the Hooks or Parameters That Are Arrays sections for example syntax.

with the usage:

> datatype description for an argument array value

So, it seems to be part of PHPDoc. Which makes it more surprising, that you couldn't find anything about it in your listed links.

Comment: Interesting... None of the linked resources mention the tag but it's clearly documented as used by the library. I guess that's what *customized documentation schema* implies :)

Answer (score 1):

It's from a serializer/deserializer lib(or at least it seems to be, I can't find anything else remotely related)

https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#type

It's a symfony bundle too. See [here](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle)

> This annotation can be defined on a property to specify the type of
>   that property. For deserialization, this annotation must be defined.
>   The @Type annotation can have parameters and parameters can be used by
>   serialization/deserialization handlers to enhance the serialization or
>   deserialization result; for example, you may want to force a certain
>   format to be used for serializing DateTime types and specifying at the
>   same time a different format used when deserializing them.

Answer (score 1):

I've found, that in older releases of phpDocumentator @type was in fig-standards repo.
They changed it in 2014 to @var.

Here is link to git pull request:
https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/pull/55

Comment: I looks like the revert of a rename that didn't win. Nice.